# Component only renders properly when reached through link (click), not through direct URL/ refresh

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase, redux

I'm building an eCommerce Store with React + Redux + Firebase. The problem I'm facing is that the `Shop`component is rendered properly when routet on (e.g. clicking on link in nav bar), but when the page is reached through a direct URL or a page refresh, the images of the articles won't show up.

The `Shop` page fetches data of the articles from the Firestore and a downloadable URL of the images from the Cloud Storage.

Below you will find the code of my `App` component that fetches the described data from the Firestore and Storage, and dispatches this data to the Redux store. It also contains the Route to the `Shop` component.

```js
const App = props => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    const storageRef = storage.ref();
    const arr = [];
    dispatch(fetchProductsPending());

    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        await firestore
          .collection("necklaces")
          .get()
          .then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
              // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
              arr.push(doc.data());
              console.log("is")
            });
          })


          const asyncForEach = async (array, callback) => {
            for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
              await callback(array[index], index, array)
            }
          }
//Async forEach loop

          const start = async () => {
            await asyncForEach(arr, async (item) => {
              console.log(item)
              await storageRef.child(`images/${item.name}/1.png`).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
                return (
                  item.url = url
                  )
              });
              console.log(item.url)
          })
        }
          start();
        dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(arr));

      } catch (err) {
        dispatch(fetchProductsError(err));
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [])

  return (
   
        <Route path="/shop" render={({props}) => (
         <MainLayout>
           <Shop {...props}/>
         </MainLayout>
        )}>
          </Route>
```

Here the `Shop`Page that consumes the information from the Redux store:

```js
const mapState = ({ products }) => ({
  products: products.products,
  pending: products.pending
});

const Shop = props => {
  const { products, pending } = useSelector(mapState);

    return (
          <div className="row">
            {products.map((item, index) => {
              console.log(item)
              return (
                <ShopItems
                  name={item.name}
                  price={item.price}
                  key={item.id}
                  id={item.id}
                  url={item.url}
                />
              );
            })}
```

And the `ShopItems` that receive the props (the redux state) from the `Shop`component:

```js
const ArticleItems = props => {
    return (
       <div className="article">
           <Link className="items" to={`/article/${props.id}`}>
           <img className="itemPicture" src={props.url} alt=""/>
           <h6>{props.name}</h6>
           <h6>{props.price}€</h6>
           </Link>
       </div>
    )
}
```

And just in case my Redux code if necessary:

**Actions**

```
export function fetchProductsPending() {
    return {
        type: productTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_PENDING
    }
}

export function fetchProductsSuccess(products) {
    return {
        type: productTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
        payload: products
    }
}

export function fetchProductsError(error) {
    return {
        type: productTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR,
        payload: error
    }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    pending: false,
    products: [],
    error: null
}

export function productsReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case productTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_PENDING: 
            return {
                ...state,
                pending: true
            }
        case productTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                pending: false,
                products: action.payload
            }
        case productTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                pending: false,
                error: action.error
            }
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

Please help, I'm loosing my mind over this and I can't get it right. Thank you!

Comment: Most often than not, this is caused by your server lacking a rule to redirect all routes to `index.html`. See if this solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually

Comment: I see, that might be the problem. However, I don't see how a catch-all route would help in my scenario, since it is normally used to redirect when receiving a 404? In my case the page gets rendered fine, the information from the firetore is fetched, only the URL from the images is not rendered, is the catch-all still a possible solution? Could you elaborate shortly how to implement a redirect of all routes to index.html? Thanks you

Comment: React-Router and other router systems *start* their "route" at the root - remember, react-router doesn't actual *move* anything, it "just" selective renders based on the route information.  While using Netlify, I have a "_redirects" file at the root that causes this to occur; your server may have different needs

Comment: Are you using Create React App? If yes, then they have a guide for many servers on how to deploy https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/  Webpack is also configured in such a way that you can import static assets (images, CSS, etc) into your JS code and the asset is copied to the `build` folder. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/ You also can create a rule for the build folder and another for, say, the API folder.